# How to make update method to be called in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, skscene

My ViewController.h:

```
@import UIKit;
@import SpriteKit;


@interface BGGameViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SKView *skView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *finishGameButton;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *startNewGameButton;

- (IBAction)finishGame:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startNewGame:(id)sender;

@end
```

But I don't know how to make update method to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is this...

```
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
...
}
```

This needs to be in your SKScene class though, not your viewcontroller.

Comment: Have you made a SKScene class?

Comment: heh... I have created a subclass in my @implementation, but is there any way I can "catch" update method call without creating a subclass of SKScene?

Comment: I don't think so...but I'll keep an eye out.

Comment: Yeah I don't think you can. The apple doc says "Do not call this method directly; it is called exactly once per frame, so long as the scene is presented in a view and is not paused. By default, this method does nothing. Your scene subclass should override this method and perform any necessary updates to the scene."

Comment: Yep, no way to catch it without creating a subclass. Thx.